# Conversión de "carillón" a "carrillón"

Tags: historia, pronunciación, letras, fonología

Este fin de año descubrí que aunque [*carrillón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7hvpxCz) es correcto, la forma más correcta etimológicamente es [*carillón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7ZMVQUa), dado que viene de la palabra francesa *carillon*.

Aunque hay registro de la palabra *carillón* en un diccionario de 1617 (el Minsheu), la RAE no recoge la palabra en su diccionario hasta 1925. La versión *carrillón* no se introdujo hasta 2001.

En textos, en el CORDE veo un uso de *carrillón* en 1935, mientras que *carillón* aparece en un texto de 1842. Se ve por tanto que, efectivamente, la palabra se comenzó a usar con *r* y luego pasó a ser usada con *rr*.

¿A qué se debe esta conversión? ¿Qué hace que una palabra con *r* pase a ser pronunciada con *rr*? ¿Existen otras palabras que hayan sufrido esta misma evolución?

Comment: @walen sí, yo al principio también pensé que era una errata pero ya he aprendido a no fiarme, así que al momento lo consulté en el diccionario y resulta que la lección me la llevé yo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miremos a la [etimología](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/carillon) de la palabra:

- `Latin` *quaternio*

  - `Vulgar Latin` **quadrinionem*

    - `Old French` *quarrellon*

      - `French` ***carrillon*** (sig. XVII - XVIII)

        - `French` ***carillon*** (sig. XVIII - )

          - `Italian` *carillon*
          - `Spanish` *carillón, carrillón*
          - `Portuguese` *carrilhão*

Como puedes ver, la forma arcaica de la palabra francesa era *carrillon*, así que es probable que la duplicación de ortografías es debido a que el español adoptó este préstamo durante una época cuando las dos ortografías francesas eran comunes.

Esto es visible en las distintas ortografías de italiano y portugués también.

Una búsqueda en Google Ngrams parece confirmar que las dos palabras ingresaron al léxico español (común) más o menos al mismo tiempo:

[image]

---

**Fuente:**

> <sup>**Prononc. et Orth. :** [kaʀijɔ̃]. Ds *Ac.* 1694-1762 sous la forme *carrillon*; ds *Ac.* 1798-1932 sous la forme moderne.</sup>
>
> <sup>• http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/carillon</sup>

Answer (score 3):

En mi opinión es una cuestión de etimología popular o reanálisis.

Se identifica un sufijo *-ón* y la base que queda (con /ɾ/) no se identifica con nada, así que si se busca un poco se da con una base que sí existe con /r/ (*carrill‑*), aunque la relación semántica sea nula.

Answer (score 1):

No me sorprende encontrarlo así porque desde pequeño conocía la palabra "carillón" de clases de música del colegio. No sé si mi subconsciente me traiciona al sugerirme la mezcla.

Carillón, como digo, es un instrumento musical que (*grosso modo*) viene a ser como un metalófono pero en pequeño (éste a su vez es como un xilófono pero con placas de metal en lugar de madera).

Sin embargo, como apuntas, carillón también significa (RAE)

> Grupo de campanas en una torre, que producen un sonido armónico por estar acordadas.

El cual proviene del francés antiguo `QUADRINIONE`, del latín `quaternio`, grupo de 4 (campanas). Así que tiene bastante sentido.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, lo primero que se me ocurre es buscar "carrillo" y además de la acepción de moflete, tenemos `polea`.

Me inclino bastante a pensar que se debe a la icónica imagen de la bola descendiendo. La mayoría de la gente (aunque si me permitís el chiste hay quien aún se lía con los cuartos) asocia el carillón a este descenso de la bola, que evoca la liberación de alguna polea en el mecanismo del reloj. Por tanto, encuentro probable que éste sea el causante. Esto, o que el sonido recuerde al tintinear de un `carro` de caballerías.